# Improving Bash service to start/stop torrents by monitoring public IP

Tags: bash, ip, vpn, bittorrent, transmission

I am looking for feedback on my solution to monitor my public ip for torrenting.

The public IP is checked against icanhazip. If the vpn is not active, pause all torrents. If vpn is active, then a check for any torrents that are downloading is made. If at least one is downloading then a all are started/queued, otherwise nothing is done because all torrents are paused.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Torrent/VPN Watch Service

while :
do
ip=$(curl -s icanhazip.com)
pchk=$(transmission-remote -tall -i | grep -a State | grep -ao Down | head -1)
if [ "$ip" = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ] ; then
    date
        echo "WARNING! The Current IP is: $ip"
        echo "Torrents are being stopped!"
    echo "Openvpn is being restarted!"
        echo
    sleep 5
        /usr/bin/transmission-remote -tall --stop > /dev/null 2>&1
        pkill -9 screen
    screen -wipe > /dev/null 2>&1
        pkill -9 openvpn
    screen -dmS openvpn /usr/sbin/openvpn /usr/local/sbin/tvw/file.ovpn
fi
if [ "$pchk" = "Down" ] ; then
    date
    echo "The Current IP is: $ip"
    echo "Torrents are active!"
    echo
    sleep 5
    /usr/bin/transmission-remote -tall --start > /dev/null 2>&1
else
    date
        echo "Current IP: $ip"
    echo "All torrents are paused."
    echo
    sleep 5
fi
done
exit
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make the torrent client aware of whether or not they're connected to an appropriate network, instead of just checking the IP address?

Comment: Network manager allows you to execute things on connect and disconnect of a connection. So, that's what I do: start and stop activities using that

Comment: Btw, please write a better title! Your current title doesn't describe your problem, so I bet a lot of experts have just scrolled over it without taking notice. Something like "run BitTorrent client only when connected to VPN" would describe it mich better!

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a problem here? If you just want a code review, you should probably delete this and ask on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi. I am still unlearned when it comes to managing linux and welcome any suggestions. This was a first working draft of the bash and the method used to check the public ip is as such because I couldn't figure out how to incorporate network manager into what I was trying to do at the time.

Comment: Transmission has a config option called "BindAddressIPv4". Set that to your vpn ip.  If your vpn goes down, then all traffic from transmission will cease.

Comment: What you really want to do is: Check if your vpn is running; Determine your vpn ip; Make sure your vpn ip is the same as ip defined in Transmission's BindAddressIPv4; If yes, you're OK; If not, set the correct ip in BindAddressIPv4 and restart Transmission

Comment: @rr0ss0rr it sounds like if all traffic ceases that I will also not be able to access and I thought if I bind to the vpn IP that I also wouldn't be able to manage the transmission-daemon via the gui software. The device running the transmission-daemon / openvpn services only downloads torrents, then transmit them via NFS to my media server.

Comment: The only traffic that will cease is the BitTorrent traffic.  This acts like a vpn kill switch (just for the transmission app)

Comment: Okay. I read this again: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/transmission-daemon/transmission-daemon.1

Seems like I have to use --bind-address-ipv4 and --rpc-bind-address to make this work.

Comment: Looks good.  I'm running on a Mac so the process is a little different. Do you know how to get the vpn ip?

Comment: Well. I assume you mean the tun0 device when openvpn starts running and that starts with a 10.x.x.x, 10 being the only number that doesn't change. That IP can changes each time the system reboots/vpn reconnects so I am looking for a way to configure my system/openvpn to issue a static IP for tun0.

Comment: Correct.  And the digit within the tun interface may also fluctuate (tun1, tun2...).  I run a check every 15 minutes that verifies the ip associated with the tun interface with the ip passed via --bind-address-ipv4.  If not, restart transmission with the correct bind ip

Comment: Would you post your script?

Comment: Since the Transmissions invocation and BindAddressIPv4 are handled differently on the Mac, I don't think it will help you. `pgrep openvpn` to see if openvpn is active.  If yes, run the ifconfig below to get the tun ip and compare to the bind ip.  For that piece, just record the ip you use to start transmission and compare to that.

Answer (score 0):

Only tested on MacOS

What you really want to do is: Check if your vpn is running; Determine your vpn ip; Make sure your vpn ip is the same as ip defined in Transmission's BindAddressIPv4; If yes, you're OK; If not, set the correct ip in BindAddressIPv4 and restart Transmission

The following line will grab your vpn utun interface and ip

`read -r vpninterface vpnip < <(/sbin/ifconfig -a | awk '/^[a-zA-Z]/{sub(/:/,""); x=$1}/inet /{print x, $2}' | awk '/utun/')`

The ifconfig + 1st awk is giving you a one liner for each interface that shows the "interface name" and "ip".  The second awk just grabs the utun info.  The check that verifies the utun ip with the BindAddressIPv4 ip should run at some interval (mine runs every 15 minutes)

Comment: My solution has changed somewhat.  

I made the following a script:
`ip=$(ip addr show tun0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')`  
`sed -i '9s/.*/    "bind-address-ipv4": "'$ip'",/' /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`  

Inlcuded this in the transmission-daemon.service file  
`ExecStartPre=/var/lib/transmission-daemon/.config/script.sh`